# Удалить несколько последовательных строк средствами sed

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash, sed

Есть файл, содержащий текст типа:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'

# Database

from . import database

DATABASES = {
    'default': database.config()
}
```

как видно, список DATABASE занимает несколько строк, и нужно удалить эту переменную средствами sed. В результате должно получиться:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'

# Database

from . import database
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Как насчёт `sed '/^DATABASES = {/,/^}$/d' file > newfile`?

Comment: Спасибо. А можете объяснить как это работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать

```
sed '/^DATABASES = {/,/^}$/d' file > newfile
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/oHReQN)

Тут первый шаблон находит строку, начинающуюся с `DATABASES = {`, потом второй шаблон с того самого места ищет строку равную `}`, и, когда находит, оператор `d` удаляет все строки вместе с найденными.